# Replacing menu item text with user's name upon login in

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to replace a Wordpress menu item text (Login) with the name after a user logs in successfully.

I have a menu item with `{display_name}` as the navigation label.

Inside `functions.php` I have so far got the following.

```
function give_profile_name(){
    $user=wp_get_current_user();
    $name=$user->user_firstname; 
    return $name;
}
add_shortcode('profile_name', 'give_profile_name');
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'my_dynamic_menu_items' );
function my_dynamic_menu_items( $menu_items ) {
    foreach ( $menu_items as $menu_item ) {
        if ( '#name_a#'==$menu_item->title ) {
            global $shortcode_tags;
            if ( isset( $shortcode_tags['profile_name'] ) ) {
                // Or do_shortcode(), if you must.
                $menu_item->title = call_user_func( $shortcode_tags['profile_name'] );
            }    
        }
    }

    return $menu_items;
}
```

Once a user is signed in, the menu correctly appear the user's name, however once signed out the menu remain to be displaying `{display_name}` on screen. How do I potentially change that to a text like 'Login'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`is_user_logged_in()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/) to define if the user is logged in or not like so:

```
// ...
if ( '#name_a#' == $menu_item->title ) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { // If logged in, get the name.
        global $shortcode_tags;

        if ( isset( $shortcode_tags['profile_name'] ) ) {
            // Or do_shortcode(), if you must.
            $menu_item->title = call_user_func( $shortcode_tags['profile_name'] );
        }    
    } else { // If not, show "Login".
        $menu_item->title = __( 'Login', 'so_48051986' );
    }
}
// ...
```